# How to find negative number in a column, which is followed by a positive number

Tags: sql, oracle, negative-number

I have a historical table `XY` with these contents:

```
 ID   Person_ID   Balance_on_account   ts
---- ----------- -------------------- ----------
 01   05          +10                  10.10.14
 02   05          -10                  20.10.14
 03   05          -50                  30.10.14
 04   05          +50                  30.10.14
 05   05          -10                  30.10.14
 06   06           11                  11.10.14
 07   06          -40                  15.10.14
 08   06           +5                  16.10.14
 09   06          -10                  30.10.14
```

and I need to create an SQL query which will give me those `Person_ID`'s and timestamps where are

- a) the `Balance_on_account` is negative - that's the easy one,
- b) and at the same time is the record of negative `Balance_on_account` followed by a positive number.

Like for `Person_ID = 05` I would have the row with `ID = 05`, and for `Person_ID = 06` the row with `ID = 09`.

Comment: Please add a tag to show the specific database platform you are using

Comment: Hi, sorry. I am using an Oracle Developer

Comment: your example is a bit confusing. rows 05 and 09 are the last rows of person_ids 05 and 06.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.
I wanted to show as clearly as possible that I DON'T want for Person_ID 05 row 02, and for Person_ID 06 row 07.
The reason is I need to see how many days is every Person_ID in debt.
I hope is clear now, if not, just ask, I asap answer as best as I can :)

Answer (score 2):

I never used it, but you could try analytic LEAD function

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Person_ID, Balance_on_account, ts
           LEAD (Balance_on_account, 1) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY ID) next_balance
    FROM XY)
WHERE Balance_on_account < 0 and next_balance >= 0
ORDER BY ID
```

LEAD lets you access the following rows in a query without joining with itself.
PARTITION BY groups rows by Person_ID so it doesn't mix different person's balances and ORDER BY defines the order within each group.
The filtering cannot be done in the inner query because it'd filter out the rows with positive balance.

next_balance will be null for the last row.

source [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i81407) and [LEAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm#i83834)

Comment: Thank you! :), it's not working, it's showing records for duplicite Person_ID and not for Balance_on_account to actual date,
but I think maybe the LEAD will be the answer.
I'm trying everything what cross my mind, but so far with no result.

Comment: you need only the last balance for each person?

Comment: @Yte please add what you expect as result to your example.

Comment: Please add to your question example what result you expect (which rows).

Comment: Hi, I already did - in a comment above where I was replaying to you>>
_"Yes, that's correct. I wanted to show as clearly as possible that I DON'T want for Person_ID 05 row 02, and for Person_ID 06 row 07. The reason is I need to see how many days is every Person_ID in debt. I hope is clear now, if not, just ask, I asap answer as best as I can :)"_

Answer (score 0):

The following query should give you the expected results provided the database platform you are using supports `Common Table Expressions` and `Window Functions` e.g. SQL Server 2008 and up.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29e64d/4)

```
WITH TsOrder AS
(
    SELECT
        Id
        , Person_Id
        , Balance_on_account
        , ts
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Person_Id
                            ORDER BY ts, Id) AS ts_Order

    FROM
        [TableName]
)

SELECT
    *

FROM
    TsOrder
    LEFT JOIN TsOrder AS NextTs
        ON  TsOrder.Person_id = NextTs.Person_Id
            AND TsOrder.ts_order = NextTs.ts_order - 1

WHERE
    TsOrder.Balance_on_account < 0
    AND NextTs.Balance_on_account > 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm affraid I can not use it in my Oracle Developer